# How to view AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment process log in case of failure

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, zip

I have a PHP application that is deployed on `Elastic Beanstalk` for latest changes, code directory is zipped (Development on windows environment) and then uploaded by "Upload & Deploy" option. It process every thing and finally fails due to some health check issue.

```
ERROR   During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
ERROR   Instance id(s) 'unique-instance-id' did not pass health check after command execution. Aborting the operation.
INFO    Command execution completed on 1 of 2 instances in environment.
INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
```

This problem does not occur if code directory is zipped on `MacBook` and then uploaded.

I can assume there could be some issue with `EOL End of line` or may be other zip format for `windows` and `linux`

I googled a lot but the solution are to upload the to environment and then run `dos2unix` command. but I have no access to the instance. only Amazon Front end panel to upload a file.

**Question:**
I just need to know how can I view the detailed log of `Elastic Beanstalk` process log for "upload and deployment" of application process (Not the trace as I have pasted above).

I have also tried the "Logs" tab(link) left side menu. It helps to download zip file for logs contains `httpd`(access_log, error_log[very old error messages]) and some other log files.

However these log files does not help to understand why deployment failed.

Comment: Have you tried the eb cli?

Comment: Nope, never used that, How it will help me, could you please explain bit more. I will try that as well

Comment: It might because the cli will do the zipping for you so *may* prevent these issues.

Comment: The important log to look at (when you click the "Logs" link on the left) is called `eb_activity.log`. This should have more detailed information about what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue of the deployment process getting stuck on "Command execution completed on 1 of 2 instances in environment." was because the health checks were failing. They were failing because my application was expecting a 200 status code on the health check but was receiving a 302 (as seen in the access logs). This is configured in elastic beanstalk under load balancer > processes > edit > health check > HTTP code. I was debugging this for several days so I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

2. Run dos2unix on the files before you create the zip file. Dos2unix is also available for Windows.